# Passing form data

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have a form and I want to pass the form data across 2 pages. The user clicks submit it passes to the next page and is checked then it is passed to the last page. I am having trying to find out how to do this. I am currently using php, html, and javascript

Comment: use the php $_SESSIONS global.

Comment: will the user submit the second page also?

Comment: I will have to look that up I have never used that before

Comment: @rabidmachine9 no the user will have nothing to do with the second page

Comment: @shinjuo Are You trying to say when the user clicks on submit the data should go to the second page and then to the third page? you can use $_Post[] to retrieve elements from previous page, if you are submitting from first page to second page.

Comment: @Searock, yes I know how to go from one page to the next, but I need the same data to go to a third page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First page would have the form and inputs on it.

Second page (which I'm assuming it just a php script):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($name != '') {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
  // redirect to third page
}
else {
  // whatever you need to do
}
?>
```

Third page:

```
<?php
  echo $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use session to pass the values in multiple pages. Suppose you have the data like

`$_POST['field1']`, `$_POST['field2']`

Now you have to use session variable in the page

```
<?php
session_start()
$_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST['field1']
$_SESSION['field2'] = $_POST['field2']
```

Now you can use the session variables in other pages initiating `session_start()`.

Answer (score 1):

place all inputs from first page on second page as hidden elements

or

place  from first page input's values in session / database / or somewhere else and have them handy durring processing second page